# Understanding huge variance in Xamarin iOS Binding Library size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

In a Xamarin.iOS Binding library for an Objective-C native library, we have started to see huge variance in output size of the binding library DLL in the past few weeks. No ideas what could have caused this.

Our Binding library is [published to MyGet (NuGet)](https://www.myget.org/feed/abtsoftware/package/nuget/SciChart.iOS) and packages vary from 7MBytes (good!) up to 200MBytes (bad!) for not much difference in code!!

[image]

The settings for the Xamarin.iOS Binding library are pretty straight forward. We are compiling in Release mode, with AnyCPU flag.

[image]

The framework size itself is a pretty constant 15MBytes, but on inspection the framework (which is checked in to an SVN Repo) has a .svn folder which is 61 megs.

[image]
[image]

So I'm wondering to myself ... **Is there any way to tell Xamarin to ignore the .svn folder when creating binding libraries?**

Or, should we use a better package manager than an SVN repo for our compiled framework? :D

Comment: I don't think this is a scenario where you should tell Xamarin to ignore the folder. If anything this is something that you should resolve with a custom build script. Some thoughts might be to take an existing SVN project and copy into a temp project without the `.svn` folder to generate a binding. Sadly I haven't used SVN for awhile, so it's hard to say. Another thought would be to look at what's getting included into your `.csproj` to see if it's being added there(Which I doubt).

Comment: Finally, you would look at the actual Build Tasks to see what's going on.https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/e3166fbb15bd4561cea0abdc7fa6ad02b1e027e6/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Core/Xamarin.iOS.ObjCBinding.CSharp.targets

Comment: Good idea. I kind of rubber duck figured out the .svn folder was adding to the size while writing the question. Then it just becomes an exercise for the reader to exclude the folder. It's not included via Xamarin csproj, I checked. It's just picking up the whole folder ...

Comment: argh ... copying made slightly more difficult by fact it needs to work on both OSX and Windows ...

Comment: I fixed the copying error and did a bit more work on this. The .svn file is not the cause of the variance of Xamarin binding library. I created bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52485 to try to get to the bottom of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem, but I'm not sure how.

I believe that the huge variance was caused by inclusion of a .svn folder in our .framework folder, which Xamarin may have been including into the compiled Binding library.

After removing that .svn folder, the library size didn't get any smaller...

After loosing a few clumps of hair I re-installed Xamarin Studio on the mac OSX server, including completely [cleaning all Xamarin folders as per this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/).

Then, after a rebuild, the binding library size is down to a more respectable 7Mbytes.